# Why I'm not able to get session cookies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, session, python-requests, session-cookies

```
import requests

with requests.session() as c:
    res = c.get('https://onlineedlreg.dotm.gov.np/dlNewRegHome', )
login_data ={'citizenshipID': '269',
             'statusType': 'NEWLICENSE'}
response = c.post("https://onlineedlreg.dotm.gov.np/dlNewRegHome",
                  data=login_data,)
r = c.get("https://onlineedlreg.dotm.gov.np/newDlApplicationEntry_.action")
print(res.cookies)
print(response.cookies)
print(r.cookies)
```

I think I'm supposed to get some cookies for response and r variable but I'm not getting so. what could be the problem.
Code give following output:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie JSESSIONID=B70AD6C7E6780768127766637046E760 for onlineedlreg.dotm.gov.np/>]>
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Response.cookies`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.cookies) only includes the cookies sent in the response. If you want the session cookies, use [`Session.cookies`](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Session.cookies):

```
with requests.session() as c:
    res = c.get('https://onlineedlreg.dotm.gov.np/dlNewRegHome', )
    login_data ={'citizenshipID': '269',
                 'statusType': 'NEWLICENSE'}
    response = c.post("https://onlineedlreg.dotm.gov.np/dlNewRegHome",
                      data=login_data,)
    print(c.cookies)
```

Comment: @RomanK.C. If you have a new question, you should ask another question. Questions in comments are hard to answer and not useful to other users